# Inject Spring Beans into Annotation-based Bean Validator

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I wrote a custom `ConstraintValidator` for a `MultipartFile` in a Spring MVC application that looks something like this:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {MultipartFileNotEmptyValidator.class})
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface MultipartFileNotEmpty {
  String message() default "{errors.MultipartFileNotEmpty.message}";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and here's the `validatedBy` part:

```
public class MultipartFileNotEmptyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MultipartFileNotEmpty, MultipartFile>
{
  @Override
  public void initialize(MultipartFileNotEmpty annotation)
  {
    // Nothing here
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(MultipartFile file, ConstraintValidatorContext context)
  {
    return !file.isEmpty();
  }
}
```

This one works and is incredibly simple. What I would like to do is create a second to check and make sure the `MultipartFile` is not too large **according to a value stored in a database table**. Can I inject the appropriate service into the new `ConstraintValidator` class somehow in order to get the information?

Comment: Make it `@Configurable`.

Comment: Inject it's dependencies inside a controller using a setter. There is no need to auto wire everything that has a dependency.

Comment: I think it can work. Have you try it ? If the param wont change, I would prefer load that param from database at the start of the aplpication and store it in the ServletContext.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's actually nothing special at all needed to use `@Autowired`. From the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints):

> ...a ConstraintValidator implementation may have its dependencies
>   @Autowired like any other Spring bean.

Comment: Except constructor injection is not possible.  Classic spring.

Comment: @BenGeorge not true anymore. I can confirm that constructor injection works well, using Spring Boot 1.5.3, Spring version is 4.3.8

Answer (score -1):

```
@Component
public class MultipartFileNotEmptyValidator
```

Then you can use `@Autowired` and have dependencies injected. Works like a charm for me.